# php post data is always empty

Tags: php, jquery, email

i am trying to send myself an email message using jquery and php
i want the contents of the message to be decided by jquery
this is my sending code

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'http://mywebpage.com/email.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data:'test',
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                        console.log("IT WORKED");
                    },
                    failure: function(result){
                        console.log("FAILED");
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
```

this is my php script

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = $_POST["data"];
echo var_dump($_POST);
echo $message;
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

the email gets sent, but the $_POST["data"] always comes back empty
what to do ?

Comment: note, failure will never be called, even on an error. you're getting no post data because you aren't sending any post data. `'test'` isn't useable data.

Comment: use firebug to check the headers

Comment: Use the developer tools to look at the full request headers sent and report back then.

Comment: I am not sure, but try changing all `header(` to `headers(`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: are you sure?

Comment: @Akam I edited my comment, because of that; am unsure. There's no other mention of `header`, only `headers` in plural form of `mail()` function, unless there's something about the headers I am not aware of.

Comment: `data:'test'` is sending an empty POST with `key=test $_POST['test']`

Comment: the reason for headers is that i am sending from origin A into origin B, and without those headers, the call fails all together

Answer (score 0):

`data` should be the following format or a query string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mywebpage.com/email.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: 'test'
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You send the data the wrong way.Please see below how it should be

```
 data: { data: "test" }
```

And then you will be able to access using $_POST['data']

Thanks

Comment: i changed it, the output is still the same from the server : array(0) {
}
Mail Sent.